# How to use f2matlab?

Tags: matlab, fortran90, fortran77

I had downloaded f2matlab for converting fortran code to matlab. But i dont know how to use it.
There is no .exe file to install it and execute f2matlab. I am not sure how to get this around.

Comment: Open the folder in matlab, type `help f2matlab` and see what it says.

Answer (score 0):

There is no .exe file to run, it's a MATLAB function f2matlab.m. You run it in the MATLAB environment.

There is a comprehensive README file included with f2matlab, try working through the examples.